# How to apply conditional statements like 'And' and 'Or' while adding a new column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, calculated-columns

I want to add a new column to my Data frame in the following manner:

```
df['new']= np.where(df['code']== 0 or 1, 1, 0 )
```

Here, I want to assign the value 1 to the 'new' column when the values in the code column is either 0 or 1. It gives an error. But if I'm using only one condition, the statement works.

The following statement works:

```
df['new']= np.where(df['code']== 0, 1, 0 )
```

How do I use both conditions while assigning values to the new column?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value) for why your condition doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df["new"] = np.where(df["code"].isin([0,1]), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new']= np.where((df['code']== 0) | (df['code']== 1), 1 , 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `np.where`, use a boolean mask and convert it to int:

```
df['new'] = df['code'].isin([0, 1]).astype(int)
```

Example:

```
>>> df
  code
0    2
1    3
2    0
3    3
4    1

>>> df['new'] = df['code'].isin([0, 1]).astype(int)

>>> df
  code  new
0    2    0
1    3    0
2    0    1
3    3    0
4    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new'] = df['code'].isin([0,1])*1
```